# Swift Unit test: HotSwap an CLLocationManager Object

Tags: unit-testing, swift

I want to do live testing with my application. For that i need to change `CLLocationManager` object that is a member of my AppDelegate on my test function.

How can i swap my `locationManager` property object for the mocked version of `CLLocationManager` without adding a swap function at the application target?
Goal is is to keep all test code at the test target. If Swift covers all need for mocking as posted at http://nshipster.com/xctestcase/ i should be missing some trick, but:

- extensions can't access private var `_locationManager` used to store `CLLocationManager` because the extension is declared on target test and for that is part of another module.
- derivation can't change `AppDelegate` because i can't change the class of a already created object

Answer (score 0):

Rather than go to the trouble of mocking a complicated system API, why not just use the location services simulation mechanisms built into Xcode? Just go to **Product > Debug > Simulate Location** and set the location as necessary there.

Comment: Creating a mock of CCLLocationManager is not difficult using derivation. Just need to override coordinate property. Also i wan't to automate the test.
Maybe i pushing the limits, but i'm trying to get a method that i can apply easily to all objects that need to be mocked.

Comment: Good luck with that. There's a lot more to `CLLocationManager` than just an overridden `coordinate` property.

Comment: How do you override `coordinate` in Swift?